# Sort table via date

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to sort my table that i have (on page load) by date

heres what i have

```
var sortTable1 = function() {

    $("#tabledirect tbody tr")
    .detach()
    .sort(function(a, b) {

        var dataA1 = $(a)
          .find("td:eq(5)")
          .text()
          .trim();

        var dataB1 = $(b)
          .find("td:eq(5)")
          .text()
          .trim();

        return parseFloat(dataA1.substring(1)) - parseFloat(dataB1.substring(1));

    })
    .appendTo('#tabledirect');

};
```

However this is sorting a price field for me.

My table is populated via rails, I'm wanting the date closest to time now to be shown first.

Sam

Comment: Why don't you order it when you retrieve the data using the database?

Comment: because im stupid and didn't think of that? Haha!

Comment: visit this : http://jsfiddle.net/jardalu/H5ARd/